# What does scrap mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/scrap_2

> Carriers face the potential of taking drastic action — including permanent cuts in capacity and increased scrapping — if there is a prolonged downturn in demand caused by successive outbreaks of the coronavirus disease 2019 (COVID-19), maritime consultancy Drewry said Tuesday.

Source: https://www.joc.com/maritime-news/container-lines/carriers-could-make-permanent-capacity-cuts-prolonged-downturn-drewry_20200714.html

Answer (score 1):

The source is behind a subscription wall.

Occurring in the same sentence as "permanent cuts in capacity", "scrapping" may mean the destruction of a ship that is no longer used. A search for the phrase "What is scrapping in the shipping industry" brings up an article in Wikipedia called "ship breaking", which is about destruction of excess shipping vessels.
[Wikipedia "ship breaking"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_breaking)

> Ship-breaking or ship demolition is a type of ship disposal involving the breaking up of ships for either a source of parts, which can be sold for re-use, or for the extraction of raw materials, chiefly **scrap**.

> ... all ships will be eventually **scrapped**, sunk, or preserved for museums

The article mentions the word "scrap", "scrapping", "scrapped" multiple times.

The sense of that word is this:
[American Heritage Dictionary "scrap"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=scrap)
v. tr. 1. To break down into parts for disposal or salvage: ***scrap** an old stove.*